In BigQuery / SQL Should I a) Nest Data as soon as I join Tables or B) Work with Flat Data and Nest before publishing?
I'm new to nested and repeated data, I have over 10GB of data so it seems it is more efficient to use nested and repeated data, also it is easier to view and work with.
If I join my tables and make a nested table I need to unnest every time I do calculations on the nested data.
Is there a best practice for the structure of a large query with Nested data - does it take more resource to unnest for each calculation?
FWIW I break my queries down using sections 'With CTE as (calculations set 1)' etc
I'm just using the nested data ATM and unnesting for calculations
